# getWidth must be called from UI thread

Tags: android

getWidth must be called from UI thread..How do i fix it??Im trying to create pdf file..but getWidth,getHeight and getCanvas is coming up errors!!!

```
 private class PdfGenerationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        // repaint the user's text into the page
        View content = findViewById(R.id.pdf_content);

        // crate a page description
        int pageNumber = 1;
        PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(content.getWidth(),
                content.getHeight() - 20, pageNumber).create();

        // create a new page from the PageInfo
        Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        content.draw(page.getCanvas());

        // do final processing of the page
        document.finishPage(page);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
        String pdfName = "pdfdemo"
                + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".pdf";

        File outputFile = new File("/sdcard/PDFDemo_AndroidSRC/", pdfName);

        try {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            document.writeTo(out);
            document.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outputFile.getPath();
    }
```

Comment: You cannot call getWidth from thread (in your case doInBackground), you can rather save width in preExecute method and use it in doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dimension of your screen like that:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

But it seems to be deprecated. Get it like that now:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int screenWidth = metrics.heightPixels;
int screenHeight = metrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: Where do i paste this?!THankYOu

Comment: You can put that on your onCreate(...) or pass it as a parameter (if the this class is not inside an activity)

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` runs on Different `Thread` and `UI` operations happens on `Main Thread` so you can't get `UI` related info from different `Thread`. You have to pass `UI` related data to your `AsyncTask` and have work done.

In your `Activity's` `onCreate()` method get dimensions like this

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int screenWidth = metrics.heightPixels;
int screenHeight = metrics.widthPixels;
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
```

and pass this to your `asyncTask` as follows

```
PdfGenerationTask pdfGenerationTask = new PdfGenerationTask(screenWidth, screenHeight, canvas);
pdfGenerationTask.execute();
```

and update your `PdfGenerationTask` class as follows

```
private class PdfGenerationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    int width, height;
    Canvas canvas;
    PdfGenerationTask(int width, int height, Canvas canvas) {
       this.width = width;
       this.height = height;
       this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        // repaint the user's text into the page
        View content = findViewById(R.id.pdf_content);

        // crate a page description
        int pageNumber = 1;
        PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(width,
                height - 20, pageNumber).create();

        // create a new page from the PageInfo
        Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        content.draw(canvas);

        // do final processing of the page
        document.finishPage(page);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
        String pdfName = "pdfdemo"
                + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".pdf";

        File outputFile = new File("/sdcard/PDFDemo_AndroidSRC/", pdfName);

        try {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            document.writeTo(out);
            document.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outputFile.getPath();
    }
```

Comment: Okay done..but getCanvas()); comes up wd the same error??

Comment: pass your canvas in same was as we have passed width and height

Comment: int canvas = metrics.?         thnq!!

Comment: @SwagatamDutta did that help you?

Comment: I solved problem of AsyncTask but now you need to figure out why it is not working as i don't have your full code, you may accept my answer if this is a good answer to your question

Comment: okay ..plz tell me where do i paste this..PdfGenerationTask pdfGenerationTask = new PdfGenerationTask(screenWidth, screenHeight, canvas);
pdfGenerationTask.execute();

Comment: Put that in place where you have previously called your AsyncTask

Comment: Its still not going through mate..Ol im trying to do is to convert an android activity to a pdf file..Can you guide me on how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Implement onPreExecute of AsyncTask and Do the calling of getHeight,getWidth and getCanvas

```
private class PdfGenerationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
     @Override
     protected String onPreExecute(Void params){
        this.height=getHeight();
        this.width=getWidth();
     }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        // repaint the user's text into the page
        View content = findViewById(R.id.pdf_content);

        // crate a page description
        int pageNumber = 1;
        PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(content.getWidth(),
                content.getHeight() - 20, pageNumber).create();

        // create a new page from the PageInfo
        Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        content.draw(page.getCanvas());

        // do final processing of the page
        document.finishPage(page);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
        String pdfName = "pdfdemo"
                + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".pdf";

        File outputFile = new File("/sdcard/PDFDemo_AndroidSRC/", pdfName);

        try {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            document.writeTo(out);
            document.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outputFile.getPath();
    }
```